# how to use opencv2.3 headerfiles in opencv2.1

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using **openCv 2.1**, I am trying to save the `cv::Mat featureVect` in `.xml` format.
The featureVect  is Intialised and it having the data. When I am using the below code

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

cv::FileStorage fs("myFile.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "Feature_Mtx" << featureVect;
```

I am getting the error. i.e #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" is not included.
I know that above header file is not in the directory `C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv` 
and this header files present in **opencv2.3**. Is it possible to use this header file in my program i.e in **opencv2.1**.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do that? You're begging for horrible debugging sessions!

Comment: execute the program using opencv2.1 instead of opencv2.3

Comment: The header files you use must match the compiled library unless the interface did not change, or things will not work.

Comment: Can't you simply upgrade to OpenCV 2.3.1?

Comment: Thank you karlphillip, i simply upgraded opencv2.1 to opencv2.3. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Create a header file `opencv2/opencv.hpp` which simply includes each module's header file (which is what opencv.hpp does).
2. Include the correct header file: `opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp` instead or `opencv2/opencv.hpp`.